# Compiling xv6 code but giving the errors on assembly instruction

Tags: shell

I am using Ubuntu 18.04.2 LTS under windows 10 by using "Windows subsystem for Linux." I am experiencing some issues with XV6.

I set up XV6 by using the command:

```
git clone git://pdos.csail.mit.edu/xv6/xv6.git
sudo apt-get install libc6-dev
chmod 700 -R xv6-riscv
```

But when I typed in `make` command, I having the following issue:

```
***
*** Error: Couldn't find an riscv64 version of GCC/binutils.
*** To turn off this error, run 'gmake TOOLPREFIX= ...'.
***
gcc    -c -o kernel/entry.o kernel/entry.S
kernel/entry.S: Assembler messages:
kernel/entry.S:17: Error: no such instruction: `la sp,stack0'
kernel/entry.S:18: Error: no such instruction: `li a0,1024*4'
kernel/entry.S:19: Error: no such instruction: `csrr a1,mhartid'
kernel/entry.S:20: Error: no such instruction: `addi a1,a1,1'
kernel/entry.S:21: Error: too many memory references for `mul'
kernel/entry.S:22: Error: too many memory references for `add'
kernel/entry.S:26: Error: no such instruction: `j junk'
<builtin>: recipe for target 'kernel/entry.o' failed
make: *** [kernel/entry.o] Error 1
```

Can anyone help me with this? (I am using an x64 system)

Comment: Normally, open source codes come with auto-configuration tools.  You may want to type 'configure' to auto config your system (for example, x86-64, ppc, arm, ...).  Or, try to find a text file called "INSTALL" or "README" and follow the directions.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

you should check this link: https://pdos.csail.mit.edu/6.828/2019/tools.html

for me I am running ubuntu, so I compiled the toolchain myself and then it works

Answer (score 3):

I was running MacOS and had the same error. I solved it by updating the `~/.bashrc` with:

```sh
PATH=$PATH:/usr/local/opt/riscv-gnu-toolchain/bin
```

before sourcing it or open a new interactive session. Then `make qemu` under `xv6-riscv` just ran!

So I would suggest you go back and check if you've finished each step: install toolchain, update env vars, source, and make.

Comment: I have the same issue I use ZSH and already added 'export PATH=$PATH:/usr/local/opt/riscv-gnu-toolchain/bin' - but it still does not work. any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

For Suse you can install cross-riscv64-gccX package, where X is the gcc version
Then use
TOOLPREFIX=/usr/bin/riscv64-suse-linux-

it worked for me